# Autofac, how to intercept the service with an instance of a Aspect but not with the Type of Aspect?

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, autofac, aop

I have an `Autofac` as an IoC container. I want to register Aspect for the some types. I can do it like this:

```
build.RegisterType(myType).As(ImyType).EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(Aspect));
```

But what if I need to register the interceptor to the some amount of classes using not a Type of interceptor but it's instance. Lets look how I think it should look like:

```
Aspect aspectInstance = new Aspect("some data to constructor")
build.RegisterType(myType).As(ImyType).EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(aspectInstance);
```

I was doing so using Ninject IoC. but what about Autofac? 
Thx for any advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [the Autofac wiki page on Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2](https://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html). It shows an example of a `CallLogger` interceptor where it registers a lambda as the interceptor:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
       .As<ISomeInterface>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(); 
builder.Register(c => new CallLogger(Console.Out));
var container = builder.Build();
var willBeIntercepted = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
```

For your case, just switch it to register an instance.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
       .As<ISomeInterface>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(Aspect));
var interceptor = new Aspect();
builder.RegisterInstance(interceptor);
var container = builder.Build();
var willBeIntercepted = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
```

Alternatively, you can use named interceptors if you don't want your aspect to be typed.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
       .As<ISomeInterface>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy("my-aspect-instance");
var interceptor = new Aspect();
builder.RegisterInstance(interceptor)
       .Named<IInterceptor>("my-aspect-instance");
var container = builder.Build();
var willBeIntercepted = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
```

Again, [check out the wiki](https://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) - there are lots of ways to associate the interceptor with the class being intercepted, including named, typed, attributes... lots of samples on the wiki.